# sed DON'T remove extra whitespace

Tags: bash, sed

It seems everybody else wants to remove any additional whitespace, however I have the opposite problem.

I have a file, call it some_file.txt that looks like

```
a     b c     d
and    some     more
```

and I'm reading it line-by-line with sed,

```
num_lines=$(cat some_file.txt | wc -l)
for i in $(seq 1 $num_lines); do
    echo $(sed "${i}q;d" $file)
    string=$(sed "${i}q;d" $file)
    echo $string
done
```

I would expect the number of whitespace characters to stay the same, however the output I get is

```
a b c d
a b c d
and some more
and some more
```

So it seems that the problem is with sed removing the extra whitespace between chars, anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this example:

```
$ echo Hello       World
Hello World
$ echo "Hello       World"
Hello       World
```

`sed` is not your problem, your problem is that bash removes the whitespaces when passing the output of `sed` into `echo`.

You just need to surround whatever `echo` is supposed to print with double quotation marks. So instead of

```
echo $(sed "${i}q;d" $file)
echo $string
```

You write

```
echo "$(sed "${i}q;d" $file)"
echo "$string"
```

The new script should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
file=some_file.txt
num_lines=$(cat some_file.txt | wc -l)
for i in $(seq 1 $num_lines); do
    echo "$(sed "${i}q;d" $file)"
    string=$(sed "${i}q;d" $file)
    echo "$string"
done
```

prints the correct output:

```
a     b c     d
a     b c     d
and    some     more
and    some     more
```

However, if you just want to go through your file line by line, I strongly recommend something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < some_file.txt
```

Question from the comments: What to do if you only want 33 lines starting from line x. One possible solution is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -i s=$1
declare -i e=${s}+32
sed -n "${s},${e}p" $file | while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

(Note that I would probably include some validation of `$1` in there as well.)

I declare `s` and `e` as integer variables, then even `bash` can do some simple arithmetic on them and calculate the actual last line to print.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, the string assignment and echo is the exact as mine

Comment: Nope, I have quotation marks around whatever `echo` is told to print.

Comment: I am trying to go through the file line by line, however only for x(=33) lines starting at line# specified by $1, is there still a better way to do this than with sed?

Comment: I've updated with one possible solution. There are probably a hundred different ones.

Comment: Nice answer. +1. One fun alternative way to get the number of lines is: `readarray junk < inputfile.txt; num_lines=${#junk[@]}`. This approach avoids a subshell and pipeline, using only bash builtins.

Comment: Notice that your while loop still swallows whitespace, namely if the line begins with it; you have to use `while IFS= read` to avoid that. And it's always a good idea to use `read -r` to avoid interpretation of backslash escapes, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: @BenjaminW.: Excellent advice; just for the record: `read line` will not just trim leading, but also trailing whitespace from the line.

Comment: ++ for the `declare -i` + arithmetic-on-assignment tip alone, but please make the `read` commands more robust, as suggested.

Comment: I've made the changes. Thanks